# Print Equation of plotted fit line - Fourier

Tags: matlab, graph, line

Ive written the code to draw a fourier series fit line on my scattered data, but i cant think how to print the equation of the line,
for my quadratic fit when solivng

```
phi = [ones(NN,1),datax1T,datax1T.^2,datax1T.^3];
```

i would use

```
s=sprintf('y=%8f+%8fx+%8fx^2+%8fx^3',aa(1),aa(2),aa(3),aa(4));
```

here is my code for my fourier fit line

```
load('fitdata.mat', 'datax1', 'datay1'); format long

datax1T =(datax1)'; %transpose of the data
datay1T =(datay1)';
k=1;

%Calculate number of data points
NN = length(datax1T);
%Calculate Design Matrix
phi = [ones(NN,1),sin(k*datax1T), cos(k*datax1T), sin(2*k*datax1T), cos(2*k*datax1T)];
%Solve System equations
aa= phi\datay1T;
%Calculate fitted values of y
yfit = phi*aa;
%Plot the output
plot(datax1T, datay1T, 'ro', datax1T, yfit, 'k-');

%Tidy up graph
s=sprintf('y=?????',aa(1),aa(2),aa(3)??); %what to put here?
legend('data',s,,'Location','southeast');
title ('Fourrier Fit Function','FontSize', 20) 
xlabel('x data'); ylabel('y data');
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using 'text'?

```
sprintf(X,Y, ['y=',aa(1),'+',aa(2),'x+',aa(3)','x^2+',aa(4),'x^3']);
```

X and Y are the coordinates of where you wanna print it

Comment: sorry if i wasnt clear, the fit line for my cubic function i have been able to display, using s=sprintf('y=%8f+%8fx+%8fx^2+%8fx^3',aa(1),aa(2),aa(3),aa(4));

Comment: it it for a different fit line, the fourier series, which i have drawn the fit line using the above code, but i cannot work out how to print the equation